# Mathematical literature for Dirichlet-multinomial integration

Tags: integration, analysis

I am playing with topic models (Latent Dirichlet Alocation + modifications) and 
would be grateful for pointers to mathematical analysis literature that covers 
details of the derivations.

For example, to derive gibbs sampler for $p(z_i|z_{-i},w)$, one needs to marginalize over $\Theta$ 
(topic mixtures for documents) to get $p(z)$. You get:
$$ \int_\Omega p(z|\Theta)p(\Theta) d\Theta = \prod_{k=1}^M \frac{B(\alpha+n_k)}{B(\alpha)} $$.
Above, $\alpha$ is a Dirichlet prior for multinomials, $n_k$
is a vector of topic counts, and $B$ is multinomial beta: 
$$ B(\alpha) = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^K \Gamma(\alpha_i)}{\Gamma(\sum_{i=1}^{K}\alpha_i)} $$ 
To derive this relation, I suppose you can apply Fubini's theorem to split the integral over $\Theta$
(vector of topics of all documents) into a product of integrals over $\theta$s (mixture of topics for a single document) and than can apply the relation: 
$\int_{Simplex} \prod_{i=1}^K x_i^{\alpha_i-1} dX = B(\alpha) $.
But in all the analysis books I found only simple cases of Fubini's theorem, 
usualy for integrating over a rectangle.

Does anybody know a book that generalizes the theorem for more complex 
domains such as product of probabilistic simplex-es, used above?

Second example, to derive a sampler for a more complex model, i get to the integral:
$$
\int_{Sim} 
\left( \prod_{j=1}^T \theta_j^{\alpha_j-1} \right)
\left( \prod_{j=1}^{D} \frac{ B(\theta+n_j) }{B(\theta)} \right) d\theta
$$

Integration is over probabilistic simplex, $T$ and $D$ are integer constants, and $n_j$ is a vector of integers. 
Does anybody know a book that could provide insights for integrals of this kind, i.e. solve them or prove that they are intractable?